# Applying Periodic Boundary Conditions for u(x,t) array

Tags: function, numpy, for-loop

So I think I applied the periodic boundary conditions incorrectly. This the Lax Wendroff method

```
def LW_hflux_eq(a,c,delt,delx,u0,flux):
  x = np.linspace(0,L,round(L/delx))
  t = np.linspace(0,(L/a)/4,round(((L/a)/4)/delt))

  u_arr = np.zeros((len(x),len(t)+1))

  # Intial Condition
  u_arr[:,0] = u0 


  countx = np.arange(1,len(x)-1)
  countt = np.arange(0,len(t))

  #Lax-Wendroff (no limiter)
  for l in countt:
      for j in countx:
          u_arr[j,l+1] = u_arr[j,l] - c*(u_arr[j,l]+(((1-c)/2)*(u_arr[j+1,l]-u_arr[j,l])*flux) - (u_arr[j-1,l]+((1-c)/2)*(u_arr[j,l]-u_arr[j-1,l])*flux))
    u_arr[-1,l+1] = u_arr[-2,l] 
    u_arr[0,l+1] = u_arr[-1,l]    
return u_arr
```

The last two lines before the return are the PBC. Am i doing this correctly? I am getting weird errors done the road when applying this function. Trying to find the root cause of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you need more information!

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Consider creating a dataset with known result and see if that works